# (Virtualbox) Move seamless guest windows between XFCE worksapces

Tags: virtualbox

Is there any way to move windows ,running inside Virtualbox in seamless mode, to different workspaces?

Host os: Fedora 18 XFCE

Guest os: Windows 7